# Trigonometry related to Rogers–Ramanujan identities

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, ramanujan

For integers $n\ge2$ and $k\ge2$, fix the notation
$$
[m]=\sin\frac{\pi m}{nk+1} \quad\text{and}\quad
[m]!=[1][2]\dots[m], \qquad m\in\mathbb Z_{>0}.
$$
Consider the following trigonometric numbers:
$$
a_i=\frac{[i+k-2]![n-i+k-2]!}{[k-2]![n+k-2]!},
\qquad i=1,2,\dots,n-1.
$$
Is it possible for any $n$ to express the quantities
$$
A_j=1-\frac{[k-1]\cdot [n+k-1]}{[j+k-1]\cdot [n-j+k-1]},
\qquad j=1,2,\dots,n-1,
$$
as a product/quotient of terms of the form
$(1-\text{product of some }a_i)$? If not (for $n\ge4$),
is it possible to prove that?

The affirmative answer is known for $n=2$ and $n=3$.
Namely, if $n=2$ so that we have only one $a_1$ and one $A_1$, then
$$
A_1=1-a_1.
$$
If $n=3$, then
$$
A_j=(1-a_j)(1-a_1a_2) \quad\text{for } j=1,2.
$$
(The last formula is a nice trigonometric identity, by the way.)

My question is motivated (in a very sophisticated way) by a recent
[question on Rogers–Ramanujan identities](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29117/).
The latter one reminded me about the problem of possible $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ generalizations of RRs
in their classical form "a $q$-sum"="a $q$-product". Only the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ are known;
these are the Andrews–Gordon identities and the Andrews–Schilling–Warnaar identities
(see [[S. Ole Warnaar, *Adv. in Math.* **200** (2006) 403--434]](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410592)).
An indirect implication of such identities is the family of (highly nontrivial)
numerical identities for the dilogarithm function; these come as the limit $q\to1$ specialisation
and some multivariate asymptotics. The trigonometric identities above come into
play from these considerations for $n=2$ and $n=3$; any answer for $n>3$ can shed
some light on the existence of new RRs.

Comment: Wadim, do you mean that in the "product of some $a_i$" and in the "product/quoient" each term appears at most once? If so, the answer is NO with a counterexample $n=4$, $k=3$, $j=1$. Proof is done by brute-force of all such possible products/quotients.


Comment: Max, a natural requirement is to have all the multiples in the product/quotients of the form $1\pm a_{j_1}\dots a_{j_k}$ where $j_1,\dots,j_k$ are not necessarily distinct.

Comment: do these have to hold for arbitrary $k$, or is $k$ fixed? If $k=1$, things become much nicer but that is disallowed here :-\

Comment: There still doesn't seem to be a small such expression for $n=4, k=3, j=1$. Considering all terms of the form $1\pm \prod_{i \in S} a_i$ for multisets $S$ of up to seven elements and using LLL lattice reduction to search for an integer relation between $\log A_j$ and $\log (1\pm \prod_{i \in S} a_i)$, I'm not finding anything. [Sage code here](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/f48083384fe93762504000a1ae64a19b).