# Bounding higher derivatives of $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)^r$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-series

Let $r\in \lbrack 0,\infty)$. Define $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)^r$. It would seem to be the case that $$|f^{(k)}(x)|\leq \frac{2r \cdot (2r+1) \dotsb (2r + k-1)}{(1+x^2)^{r + k/2}}$$ for all even $k\geq 0$. What would be a clean, short proof?

Note that
$$\left(\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^r}\right)^{(k)} = \frac{P_k(x)}{(1+x^2)^{r+k}},$$
where $P_k\in \mathbb{Z}\lbrack x\rbrack$ is given by the recurrence formula
$$P_k(x)=1,\;\;\;\;\;\;P_{k+1}(x) = P_k'(x) (1+ x^2) + 2 (r+k)\cdot x P_k(x).$$
It should not be too hard to work out all the coefficents of $P_k(x)$; the leading terms are $$(-1)^{k+1} \cdot 2r \cdot (2r+1) \dotsb (2r + k-1)\cdot \left(x^k - \binom{k}{2} \frac{x^{k-2}}{2 r + 1} + \dotsc\right).$$ The desired bound should then follow after some work -- but I am hoping for a better proof.

Comment: I would try integral representation like $\Gamma(r)\cdot (1+x^2)^{-r}=\int_0^\infty e^{-t(1+x^2)}t^{r-1}dt$ (or better some more clever).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well,
$$
(a^2+x^2)^{-r}=(x+ai)^{-r}\cdot (x-ai)^{-r}.
$$
Differentiate this $k$ times, we get
$$
\left((a^2+x^2)^{-r}\right)^{(k)}=k!\sum_{s=0}^k {-r\choose s}{-r\choose k-s}
(x+ai)^{-r-s}(x-ai)^{-r-(k-s)}.
$$
Estimate this by the triangle inequality, you get some constant times $(x^2+a^2)^{-r-k/2}$. But for $a=0$ we have equality (because the signs of all summands are equal to $(-1)^k$), thus the constant is
$$
(-1)^kx^{2r+k}\left(x^{-2r}\right)^{(k)}=2r(2r+1)\ldots(2r+k-1).
$$

Comment: That's very nice :)

Comment: Excellent example of an answer to this question as well: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30156/demystifying-complex-numbers/248469#248469